# How can an empty Map be created in Sass?

Tags: sass, sass-maps

The following code will create an empty map in the variable `$test`, but is there a proper way to accomplish the this? This seems too hackish to be the best way to get an empty map.

```
$test: map-remove((default:null), 'default');

@if type-of($test) != map {
    @warn "This is not a map: #{inspect($test)}";
}
@else {
    @warn "This is a map: #{inspect($test)}";
}

WARNING: This is a map: ()
         on line 7 of app/styles/functions/map.scss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better native way to do that, but you could make it shorter.

```
$map: map-remove((x:x), x);

.foo {
  output: type-of($map); // map
}
```

---

Another solution would be to use a custom function.

```
@function empty-map($x: x) {
  @return map-remove(($x:$x), $x);
}

$map2: empty-map();
$map3: empty-map();

.foo {
  output: type-of($map2); // map
  output: type-of($map3); // map
}
```

[SassMeister demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/1fb65db743c323c2ff29f03447c46e76)

Answer (score 2):

Empty maps can be created in a very simple way:

```
$emptyMap: ();
```

According to the [official documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) on maps, empty lists and maps are both created using just `()`. So the above code is a perfectly valid empty map, but when testing the type, the console will tell you it's a list (note that its type is still either map or list).

```
$map: ();
@warn "#{type-of($map)}";
// Warning: list
```

Once you add something to the map, the console will tell you it's a map.

```
$map: ();
$newMap: map-merge($map, (1: test));
@warn "#{type-of($newMap)}";
// Warning: map
```

Comment: I understand. I don't intent to add anything to it, but I do intent to pass it through `map-has-key()`, and this is a problem if the type is `list`.

Comment: Even though the console reports an empty map as a list, it is still considered either an empty map or empty list. You can pass it through `map-has-key()` just fine.

Comment: Humm... Yes, seems so. I swear I was getting a error with it earlier.

Comment: If this solution works for you, please accept it as the correct answer.